# Get last executed query in MySQL with PHP/CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

How can I get last query I ran in MySQL in both Windows and Linux?

I am working with PHP and CodeIgniter. In `my_model.php`, I have:

```
$query1 = ( ...something... );
$query2 = ( ...something... );
$variables = ( .... something .... );
$this->db->query(" $query1 ... $variables .. $query2", array( $variables, ... ));
```

I need the last query executed right after the code snippet above.

Can anyone tell me how can I get my last query?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no generic "get the last query" function. What do you need it for?

Comment: @Pekka, CodeIgniter has this built-in :-)

Comment: @Rocket ah, fair enough.

Comment: Other useful functions if your are debugging are mysql_errno(); // Returns the error number of the last MySQL operation 3 mysql_error(); // Returns the error description of the last MySQL operation mysql_info(); // Returns information about the last query

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Use:

```
$this->db->last_query();

Returns the last query that was run (the query string, not the result). Example:
$str = $this->db->last_query();

// Produces: SELECT * FROM sometable....
```

example taken from the manual on [query helper functions](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/helpers.html)

Comment: got this: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli::last_query()

Comment: @AhmadAmeri Note that the answer refers to a 9 years ago version of Codeignter, and PHP.

Comment: do you have any idea how can i get latest query?

Answer (score 4):

In the config/database.php the config array must be set: 'save_queries' => TRUE, if it is false not working the last_query() function.

Answer (score 3):

In CodeIgniter there is a helper function `$this->db->last_query();`.

This will return the string of the last query.

But I think you might be asking how to obtain the result, in which case you'd do:

```
$query1 = ( ...something... );
$query2 = ( ...something... );
$variables = ( .... something .... );
$query = $this->db->query(" $query1 ... $variables .. $query2", array( $variables, ... ));

foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
//code goes here
}
```

For more information, take a look a [CI's examples](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/examples.html).